# Struggling with Opaque Pointers in SQLITE swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, opaque-pointers

Hi I am new to swift and attempting to add a database for my a level coding project. I cannot seem to get opaque pointers to work without errors. I have used tutorials and always get the same errors.
The errors that I get:

```
Expected member name or constructor call after type name on line 3
```

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?.Type>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>' On line 9
```

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'OpaquePointer?.Type' to return type 'OpaquePointer?' On line 12
```

```
    var dbURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    
    func createDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?{
        var db = OpaquePointer?
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dbURL)
        
        if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite"){
            let filePath = pathComponent.path
            if sqlite3_open(filePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK{
                print("successfully opened database")
                
                return db
            }
          
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry just posted them now

Comment: You could help us by explaining which line is #3 and so on but I already see that your function is missing a return at the end, you need add `return nil`

Comment: Sorry it's my first post, line 3 is the 3rd line of the code I sent you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var db = OpaquePointer?` to `var db : OpaquePointer?`

Add `return nil` to the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a colon instead of a equal sign on line 3.